# Creating matched pairs in R

Tags: r, matching

I have a data set of ~20,000 cases and 3 possible controls for each case. Cases and controls are each uniquely identified by an ID variable. The possible controls have some overlap because they were joined with the cases in SQL in a manner that did not allow for matching without replacement. I have imported the data into R and am treating it as a group of ~20,000 cases and ~50,000 controls in order to select only 1 control for each case matched on the covariates (e.g., age) in the data set. My desired output is a case ID in column 1 and a matched control ID in column 2.

I have been trying to use the MatchIt package to do the matching, but the output from the package (match.matrix) is a list of IDs that don't clearly correspond to the cases or controls. The package has a function called get_matches that seems like it would return the appropriate output, but the function arguments are opaque to me - I cannot figure out what `id_cols` and `getdata` are. There don't seem to be any tutorials on how to use MatchIt (or another package) to return just a list of the case IDs with their matched control IDs. I am using the Mahalanobis distance but don't care about the actual distance measure or returning a propensity score. What is the best package and approach for selecting just the single control who best matches each case, without replacement, and returning the case ID with the matched control ID?

Sample imported data (note the overlap between some of the possible matches):

```
case_ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
control_ID <- c(5,6,7,8,9,10,5,6,7,11,12,13)
age <- c(12,12,12,56,56,56,12,12,12,62,62,62)
score <- c(7,7,7,3,3,3,7,7,7,9,9,9)
parity <- c(1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2)
retested <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)

df <- cbind(case_ID, control_ID, age, score, parity, retested)
```

Desired output (with covariates shown):

```
matched_case <- c(1,2,3,4)
matched_control <- c(5,8,6,11)
matched_age <- c(12,56,12,62)
matched_score <- c(7,3,7,9)
matched_parity <- c(1,4,1,2)
matched_retested <- c(1,0,1,1)

matched_df <- cbind(matched_case, matched_control, matched_age, matched_score, matched_parity, matched_retested)
```

Comment: There is a [vignette for MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/matchit.pdf). R vignettes describe how a package works in more detail.Does that help?

Comment: You may want to try package [`Matching`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/index.html) which appears to be better maintained.

Comment: I read the vignette for MatchIt, but it's largely focused on assessing covariate balance after matching. They do mention a procedure for extracting case IDs and control IDs from the matched data, but it isn't working for me - I just get an empty set when I filter for IDs that I know belong to one group or the other. I looked at Matching but didn't get the sense it would perform much better in this aspect. The best option I had seemed to be optmatch, but the way it stores the matched object required too much memory (`pairmatch` threw the error "could not allocate vector of size 16.6 GB").

Comment: This can probably be solved with not more than 10 line of code.  But, there is one thing that is not clear to me, yet. I see no reason why case 1 5 12 7 1 1 must be matched with control subject 5 and the 3 6 12 7 1 1 with the 6. Is there?

Comment: In the sample data, there is no reason why case 1 is matched with control 5 and case 3 with 6 - the data from SQL has 3 controls for each case that were randomly assigned from a much larger pool of possible controls. In my real data, there are cases for which none of the possible controls exactly match on all the covariates. I generated these matches in SQL using a caliper of, e.g., age needs to match within +/- 3 years. So I'm using nearest neighbors for the matching procedure in R.

Comment: I may be slow, but does that also mean that your real data doesn't have duplicates in the covariates like we can see it in the first three lines of the data frame?

Comment: There are quite a few cases that have several exact matches among the controls (so the covariates are duplicates). But there are some cases for which either no exact match is available among the remaining possible controls, or there was never an exact match to begin with. In some ways, doing a full matching procedure in R is overkill, because I already have 3 possible matches for each case in my data from SQL. But I need to select one of those matches for each case while ensuring that controls are not repeated.

Comment: I actually don't think the formal matching procedure is going to work very well, because I've found some good possible controls that were discarded and cases matched with poor controls. I am going to ask this question a different way on another thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match by group in R without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917975/match-by-group-in-r-without-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but this code at least works on your sample. From your comments I conclude that the sample does not tell the whole story. It will be pretty slow, too. But this may be a start.

```
case_ID     <- c( 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
control_ID  <- c( 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10, 5, 6, 7,11,12,13)
age         <- c(12,12,12,56,56,56,12,12,12,62,62,62)
score       <- c( 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9)
parity      <- c( 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
retested    <- c( 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(case_ID, control_ID, age, score, parity, retested)

df$unq <- apply(df[, 2:6], 1, paste, collapse = "")
r <- 1
#discarded <- character()
while (r < nrow(df)) {
  # find all discarded and remove
  discarded <- c(df[r, "unq"]) # accept current `r` but discard the coming ones
  discarded <- which(df$unq[(r+1):length(df)] == discarded)
  if(length(discarded) > 0) {
    discarded <- discarded + r
    df <- df[-discarded, ]
  }
  # Find further instances of this case and remove
  discarded <- c(df[r, "case_ID"])
  discarded <- which(df$case_ID[(r+1):length(df)] == discarded)
  if(length(discarded) > 0) {
    discarded <- discarded + r
    df <- df[-discarded, ]
  }
  # Next!
  r <- r+1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will experiment with this. I am wondering if it behooves me to try to take better advantage of the fact that my data are coming into R from SQL with a preliminary matched structure (3:1, unfortunately with replacement). In case you have the time/interest, I created a sample data frame that I hope better explains my actual data in another post, with the question asked differently to focus on exploiting the preliminary matched structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917975/match-in-r-without-replacement.